# how to align the height of the button with the textfield to it?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: picture]

how to align the height of the `ElevatedButton` with the `TextField` to it? In the picture, the button height is higher than `TextField` .

```
ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          minimumSize: Size.zero,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0.h, horizontal: 8.0.w),
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8))),
      child: Text(
              "인증번호 요청",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0.sp, color: Colors.white),
            ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Flexible(
child :ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      minimumSize: Size.zero,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0.h, horizontal: 8.0.w),
      shape:
          RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8))),
  child: Text(
          "인증번호 요청",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0.sp, color: Colors.white),
        ),
);
)
```

you can do that like this .

Comment: Flexible is not align the height of elevatedButton.

Comment: if you want this for Shape you can use Container and decoration instead of ElevatedButton